# Unable to create complex property of custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am trying to create on multi value complex propety of custom control but written code for it not working, only multi value read only property coming in property explorer. Here is code for it

```
private MyComboProperties _MyComboProperties;

public MyComboProperties MyComboPropertiesValues
{
    get
    {
        return _MyComboProperties;
    }
    set
    {
        _MyComboProperties = value;
    }
}

//MyComboProperties struct is like this

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public struct MyComboProperties
{
    private string _MySourceQuery;
    private string _MyDisplayMember;
    private string _MyValueMember;

    public MyComboProperties(string mySourceQuery, string myDisplayMember, string myValueMember)
    {
        _MySourceQuery = mySourceQuery;
        _MyDisplayMember = myDisplayMember;
        _MyValueMember = myValueMember;
    }

    public string MySourceQuery
    {
        get
        {
            return _MySourceQuery;
        }
        set
        {
            _MySourceQuery = value;
        }
    }

    public string MyDisplayMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyDisplayMember;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyDisplayMember = value;
        }
    }

    public string MyValueMember
    { 
        get
        {
            return _MyValueMember;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyValueMember = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or else someone provide me sample code for multi value Custom Control with 3 input string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to achieve your objective.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ExpandableMultiValuedCustomControl
{
public partial class MyComboBox : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    private MyComboProperties _comboProperties = new MyComboProperties();
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyComboBox(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Category("My Combo Properties")]
    [DisplayName("My Combo Properties")]
    [Description("My Combo Properties")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public MyComboProperties MyComboProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return _comboProperties;
        }
        set
        {
            _comboProperties = value;
        }
    }
}

[DisplayName("My Combo Properties")]
[Description("CMy Combo Properties")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[DesignerCategory("Component")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]

public class MyComboProperties
{
    private string _MySourceQuery;
    private string _MyDisplayMember;
    private string _MyValueMember;
    public MyComboProperties()
    {

    }

    [Category("MyComboBoxProperties")]
    [DisplayName("MySourceQuery")]
    [Description("MySourceQuery")]
    public string MySourceQuery
    {
        get
        {
            return _MySourceQuery;
        }
        set
        {
            _MySourceQuery = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("MyComboBoxProperties")]
    [DisplayName("MyDisplayMember")]
    [Description("MyDisplayMember")]
    public string MyDisplayMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyDisplayMember;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyDisplayMember = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("MyComboBoxProperties")]
    [DisplayName("MyValueMember")]
    [Description("MyValueMember")]
    public string MyValueMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyValueMember;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyValueMember = value;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

And to access those properties you have to access like this:

```
myComboBox1.MyComboProperties.MyDisplayMember 
myComboBox1.MyComboProperties.MyValueMember 
myComboBox1.MyComboProperties.MySourceQuery
```

Comment: I've done the needful changes in answer such as added setter in MyComboProperties and commented [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)], plz do check now.

Comment: Moreover you even don't need to override any of the methods in ComboTypeConverter just declare an empty class which inherits TypeConverter.

Comment: Final version of the answer is ready and updated by me. I've optimized it to maximum possible extent.